# How to use secure flag when AuthenticationTypes.Sealing is used

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, directoryentry

I am creating a Directory Entry object using

```
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(path,
                    null, null, System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.Sealing))
```

It gives me warning: `The Secure flag must also be set to use sealing.`
What do I need to do ? I can suppress the above warning by using

```
#pragma warning disable S4433 // LDAP connections should be authenticated
```

Can you please explain me what am i missing?
Please note, I am using AuthenticationTypes.Sealing because I want to create and set the user password in AD in a single commit from performance perspective.

Kindly explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`AuthenticationTypes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.authenticationtypes) enum is  bit flag, meaning that multiple values can be combined. The error is saying that you cannot use `Sealing` without `Secure`. So you must include both, which you can do with `|`, like this:

```
DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(path,
    null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Sealing | AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
```